# Format a percentage using culture info?

Tags: c#

I'm formatting a number as a percentage using the current culture info by doing:

```
string.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, "{0:P}", num / 100);
```

I've tried `de-DE` and `en-US`. In the region settings, the number of decimal places is 2. However, the above formatting results in 3 decimal places.

Why is this happening and how do I correctly format the number based on the culture's number format?

Comment: Look into : https://stackoverflow.com/a/30376263/8843451

Answer (score 1):

Could you try to set the `PercentDecimalDigits` value in `NumberFormatInfo`?

```
CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalDigits = 2;
CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.PercentDecimalDigits = 2;
```

Reference:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.numberdecimaldigits?view=net-6.0

Answer (score 0):

The following line returns the culture's number of digits for percentages.

```
CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.PercentDecimalDigits
```

The value is 3. So the formatting is being applied correctly.